# Отладка многопоточных программ Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, отладка

Привет всем! Как в Qt отлаживать многопоточные программы? есть ли примеры или информация к размышлению?

Answer (score 2):

Наилучший способ отладки таких программ - подробное логирование. Потому как с отладчиком некоторые комбинации состояний поймать будет невозможно.

Дополнительные способы:

- писать защищенный код - проверять все, что только можно проверить при помощи `assert()`
- обязательно проверять код возврата системных вызовов
- плотно использовать RAII
- вооружитесь статическим анализатором
- и динамическим тоже - Valgrind, например

Comment: Недостатком такого подхода может являться тот факт, что при подробном логировании ошибки могут уходить, или другие появляться. Отладка многопоточных приложений это ад, просто ад.

Comment: @ixSci логировать надо во что-то жутко быстрое и надежное. Например, в очередь с механизмом lock-free.

Comment: Всё равно даст какое-то смешение по времени и баг может просто пропасть. Я бы скорее использовал возможности отладчика, по отслеживанию состояния памяти. Вообще, это реально сложная тема, автору предстоит ещё это осознать.

Comment: @ixSci - вы мне напомнили про статический и динамический анализаторы валидности, дописал в ответ.

Comment: Вот только разработка программы ведется под Windows  с Qt 4.8.5 и не выше, а Valgrind работает только под linux и mac os

Comment: Лучший способ -- вообще не писать многопоточные программы. Если очень хочется, то потоки не должны работать с общей памятью (я не шучу, каждый работает только со своим набором переменных, диапазоном элементов массива и т.п.). Для индивидуальных сообщений лучше использовать пайпы (и т.п. средства ядра).

Comment: @Disastricks увы, libastral у меня не пропатчена, так что этого я заранее знать не мог. Ради хохмы, соберите продукт под линуксом.

Comment: @avp - угу, и слить производительность, ради которой все затевается.

Comment: @gbg, слишком часто ожидаемая производительность так и не достигается (все съедает синхронизация). Если работы большие, то обычно их вообще по процессам можно разложить.

Comment: @avp - это беспредметный разговор, к сожалению.